How to pass parameter from stimulus JS controller back to modal window defined in twig template?
In short: I've got grid of purchases, once I click on any purchase, I see links detail and approve purchase. When I click on 'approve purchase', modal window appears and I should be able to approve purchase (change status parameter of any purchase). Problem is, that I don't know how to pass row._id (purchase ID) to this modal window.
This is how important part of my code looks like:
template:
<div{{ attributes.add(stimulus_controller('purchases/purchases')) }}>
    {% set debounceMs = 'debounce(1000)' %}
    {% set foundCount = this.purchasesCount %}

    {% component 'bootstrap_modal' with {targetId: 'approve-purchase-modal'} %}
    {% block modal_header %}
{#            {{ dump(app.request) }}#}
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h6>Purchase approval #{{ purchaseId }}</h6>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
    {% block modal_body %}
        <div class="filter-wrap">
            <form id="approve-purchase-form" class="f-column">
                <div class="form-group center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm agree d-flex"
                            data-action="live#action"
                            data-live-action-param="prevent|approvePurchase"
                            data-live-index-param="{{ purchaseId }}"
                            data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                    >Approve
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
{% endcomponent %}

purchases_controller.js
window.detailFormatter = function (index, row) {
let html = []
html.push('<ul class="actions edit-actions ' + row._class + '">'
    +'<li><a class="blue" data-app-folder-type="purchase-detail" data-app-folder-title="'+row.desc+'" data-app-folder-id="'+row._id+'">Detail</a></li>'
    +'<li><a id="approve-purchase" title="" data-bs-purchase-id="'+row._id+'" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#approve-purchase-modal" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"'
    +'</ul>'
)
return html

How to process that
data-bs-purchase-id="'+row._id+'" 

back to twig to pass it to modal as
purchaseId

This is not possible as Twig(/Symfony) is rendered server-side - You'll need to resort to JavaScript, if you need extra information from Symfony, you can always create an AJAX request

i'm missing a lot of code to see what your exactly try todo.
Can u share te full stimulus controller en de div.
With sum assumptions i think you need a custom stimulus controller, to pass some arguments to a modal

I'm not sure I understand the whole problem, but wouldn't adding a stimulus_target('purchases/purchases', 'approveButton') to the button and adding the 'targetId' dataset from your 'purchases_controller' solve this?

@ErwanHaquet thanks for your answer, but solving this issue at button is too late for this situation. I need to know the purchaseId when opening modal window already. My problem is how to pass that row._id from purchases_controller.js to twig

so, this is the whole purchases_controller.js code
import {Controller} from '@hotwired/stimulus';
import {getComponent} from "@symfony/ux-live-component";
import '../bootstrapTableAll';

window.detailFormatter = function (index, row) {
    let html = []

    let text1 = "<ul class=\"actions edit-actions " + row._class + "\">";
    let text2 = "<li><a class=\"blue\" data-app-folder-type=\"purchase-detail\" data-app-folder-title=\""+ row.desc+ "\" data-app-folder-id=\"" + row._id + "\">Detail</a></li>";
    let text3 = ""
    if (row.status === "completed") {
        text3 = "<li><a id=\"approve-purchase\" title=\"\" data-bs-toggle=\"modal\" data-bs-purchase-id=\"" + row._id + "\" data-bs-target=\"#approve-purchase-modal\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\">Approve purchase</a></li>"
    }
   
    let text4 = "</ul>"
    let result = text1.concat(text2).concat(text3).concat(text4);

    html.push(result)
    return html
}

export default class extends Controller {
    static targets = ['dataTable']
    async initialize() {
        this.component = await getComponent(this.element).then((component) => {
            component.on('render:finished', (component) => {
                $(this.dataTableTarget).bootstrapTable()
            })
        })
    }
}


Is this an actual answer? If so then please [edit] the answer and explain what you've actually changed in order to solve the issue. If this is not an answer then should edit the question and add this new information in it.
